# liferay aui validation not working on Pop up

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

We have a sign in link in Theme. In this link we have called pop up for signing in. In that pop up there is two tabs, one for sign in and another for sign up.

For sign in we have created sign in hook and for sign up we have created a custom portlet.

I have used AUI validations for the sign up custom portlet.

- My portlet is non-instantiable.
- When I call this portlet in page, validations work out, but when I call this portlet in the theme, the AUI validations do not work.
- While calling the portlet in the theme I have removed the porlet from
  other page.

In theme this portlet is getting called from 2-3 different links.

P.S. I have also tried changing portlet to instantiable, but in that case, it doesn't get called from the theme.

Comment: Any js error in console you are seeing?

Comment: no error on console. :(

Comment: Did you put your portlet in whitelist using portal-ext.prop?

Comment: is the validation script given in the same jsp?

Comment: I used AUI tags. so yes, it is given in same jsp. This issue gets resolved some another script in liferay theme was overriding AUI.